# I need help appending words from a text file while creating a new list in list every time there is a new document

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, text, append

I've a text file containing movie reviews where every new line ('\n') represents a new movie/ new document. However, I've trouble appending them into a sequence as follows:

If given example text file:

```
 chemistry leads outstanding another story white people learn black people humanity
 trappings green book on 
 already visionary director coogler outdone film fits larger marvel universe 
 innovative directors stretching across multiple
```

Where the first two lines are the first document followed by the next two lines which is the second document.

Therefore, the goal is to convert these sentences into a "list in list" as shown below:

```
  [[chemistry, leads, outstanding, another, story, white, people, learn, black, people, humanity, trappings, green, book, on]
  , [already, visionary, director, coogler, outdone, film, fits, larger, marvel, universe, innovative, directors, stretching, across, multiple]]
```

The problem I have is I do not know how to read where there is a different document/ line and append all them in a new list in the existing list. Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

I'll be on standby to answer more questions. Thanks

MORE INFO:
I wrote to file with the following code:

```
if count == 1:
    with open('moviedata1.txt', 'a') as f:
        for item in reviews:
            f.write(item)
            f.close()
else:
    if page == 1:
        with open('moviedata1.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write('\n')
            for item in reviews:
                f.write(item)
            f.close()
    else:
        with open('moviedata1.txt', 'a') as f:
            for item in reviews:
                f.write(item)
            f.close()
```

Here is an image of the text file:
[image: view here]
where the highlighted blue is the last word before starting on the next document/line

Comment: read in the text file and use .rstrip('\n') with step=2.  then .split(' ').  write the code and then post it for additional help if needed.

Comment: The image you posted and the query as per described by you tells that you want to split sub-lines from single line. And you're not providing any value for where to split. Do you want to split after a fixed number of words?? ,If not please make sure you're clear on question.

Comment: @Vicrobot correct. I was thinking there is a way python could differentiate between them. But looks like I've to induced some values in myself? Anyway, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` and iterate:

```
s = ''' chemistry leads outstanding another story white people learn black people humanity
 trappings green book on 
 already visionary director coogler outdone film fits larger marvel universe 
 innovative directors stretching across multiple'''

lst = []
splitted = s.split('\n') 
for x, y in zip(splitted[::2], splitted[1::2]):
    lst.append(x.split() + y.split())

print(lst)

# [['chemistry', 'leads', 'outstanding', 'another', 'story', 'white', 'people', 'learn', 'black', 'people', 'humanity', 'trappings', 'green', 'book', 'on'],  
#  ['already', 'visionary', 'director', 'coogler', 'outdone', 'film', 'fits', 'larger', 'marvel', 'universe', 'innovative', 'directors', 'stretching', 'across', 'multiple']]
```

Comment: This works but the code still doesn't register '\n' in my text file. I still end up with a pattern like this [[.....]]

Comment: really sorry my file was huge so it took me a long time to figure out if everything was alright.

Comment: I haven't demonstrated how to write to file. Btw, do you want to store list to file with each sublists in new line? I wouldn't want to do the writing part as you seem to have produced no code.

Comment: I've updated the code for how I wrote to file via web scrapping which generates the image of data that I've posted as well. I'm not storing the output. I'm doing topic modelling so I need the words from each document to be analyzed per document.